# Elasticsearch group by

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elasticsearch (v. 5.2.0) index containing documents like this:

```
{
        "_index": "test-index-2017.03.15",
        "_type": "logevent",
        "_id": "AVrSIU-U8za2OFJzSCwQ",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
           "@timestamp": "2017-03-15T14:21:21.9636228+01:00",
           "level": "Information",
           "messageTemplate": "HeartbeatEntry {@Data}",
           "message": "HeartbeatEntry HeartbeatEntry { ServiceName: \"Service A\", HeartbeatValue: 1 }",
           "fields": {
              "Data": {
                 "_typeTag": "HeartbeatEntry",
                 "ServiceName": "Service A",
                 "HeartbeatValue": 1
              },
              "MachineName": "DevServer01"
           }
        },
        "sort": [
           1489584081963
        ]
     }
```

I want to get all 'ServiceName' values grouped by "MachineName". If this was in SQL world, I would do something like `SELECT ServiceName, MachineName FROM test-index-2017.03.15 GROUP BY MachineName`

I'm getting stuck pretty early, as I cant even get a simple aggregation working. Currently I got this:

```
GET /test-index-2017.03.15/_search
{
"size": 0,    
"aggs" : {
    "by_machinename" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "MachineName"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Which yields zero results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with `field: fields.MachineName`?

Comment: That gives me a "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default." exception. But if i do  "field" : "fields.MachineName.keyword" then I get results. Thanks! Now I'm half there :)

Answer (score 1):

After dome digging around and with the help of paqash's comment, this did the trick:

```
GET /test-index-2017.03.15/_search
{
"size": 0,    
"aggs" : {
    "by_machinename" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "fields.MachineName.keyword"
        },
        "aggs" : {
            "by_servicename" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "fields.Data.ServiceName.keyword"
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
}
```